# Minimize sum of unique elements in columns of a matrix by moving entries within rows

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have a matrix with $R$ rows and $C$ columns.

1.An element appears no more than once in the same row.

2.The set of elements in each row has intersection.

3.Elements in the matrix can only be moved in the same row.

Objective:
Through the movements of the elements in the same row, get the minimum sum of the numbers of unique elements in each column.

$\min(\sum_{i=1}^Cunique(column_i))$

Example:
$$\begin
{bmatrix}
{a}&{d}&{f}&{b}\\
{d}&{e}&{c}&{g}\\
{b}&{a}&{e}&{s}\\
{s}&{b}&{a}&{h}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Objective = 4+4+4+4=16

After movements:

$$\begin
{bmatrix}
{a}&{b}&{d}&{f}\\
{c}&{g}&{d}&{e}\\
{a}&{b}&{s}&{e}\\
{a}&{b}&{s}&{f}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Objective = 2+2+2+2 = 8

This is a example only with 4 columns and 4 rows. What about a matrix with many columns and rows? How to find the optimal movements policy and prove it?

Thank you!

Comment: The title is very uninformative.

Comment: I edited the title, but am not sure to understand the meaning of *"minimum sum of the numbers of unique elements in each column"* In a column, one sums all entries occurring only once?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in\{1,\dots,R\}$, let $S_i$ be the set of $C$ elements in row $i$. Let binary decision variable $x_{i,s,j}$ indicate whether row $i$ element $s$ is assigned to column $j$, and let binary decision variable $y_{s,j}$ indicate whether element $s$ appears at least once in column $j$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{s,j} y_{s,j}$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^C x_{i,s,j} &=1\\
\sum_{s\in S_i} x_{i,s,j} &=1\\
x_{i,s,j} &\le y_{s,j}
\end{align}